# How to block the installation of unsigned packages in Debian by default?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, deb

I was wondering which option in apt.conf will block by default the installation of packages with invalid signatures. I'm using Debian Wheezy 7.6

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the apt frontend you use (`apt-get`, `aptitude` etc.).

The default, at least for `apt-get` and `aptitude`, is to always check signatures and to prompt if the check failed. So the behaviour you ask for is already the default.

To override this, you can set the option "allow-unauthenticated" (as `--allow-unauthenticated option` on the commandline, or as `APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated "true";` in `apt.conf`). This will *disable* the check. If you want apt to always check, make sure this setting is not in your `apt.conf`.

If install a package non-interactively, it depends on the options you use. If you use `--assume-yes`, ìnstallation will be aborted if the signature check fails. `--force-yes` may allow the installation (I did not check).

Also see this question on askubuntu: [How do I bypass/ignore the gpg signature checks of apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74345/how-do-i-bypass-ignore-the-gpg-signature-checks-of-apt).